# F# groupBy - System.Exception : unrecognized method call

Tags: linq, f#

I'm trying to query data with F# SqlDataProvider but I got strange error when I'd like to use groupBy function

my init code :

```ml
r# "packages/FSharp.Data.2.2.5/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll"
r# "packages/SQLProvider.1.0.0/lib/FSharp.Data.SQLProvider.dll"
r# "packages/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.5.0.0.2/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"

open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.Sql
open FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open FSharp.Linq
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
open System
open System.Data

type dbSchema = SqlDataProvider<
                    ConnectionString = "my-connection-string",
                    DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER,
                    IndividualsAmount = 1000,
                    UseOptionTypes = true>
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
```

my query :

```ml
query {
    for county in db.Dbo.Countries do
    groupBy county.CountryCode into g
    select (g.Key, g.Count())
    } |> Seq.iter (fun (key, count) -> printfn "%s %d" key count)
```

I got this error :

> System.Exception: unrecognised method call
>      at Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.EvaluateQuotation(FSharpExpr e)
>      at Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.EvalNonNestedInner(CanEliminate canElim, FSharpExpr queryProducingSequence)
>      at Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.clo@1735-1.Microsoft-FSharp-Linq-ForwardDeclarations-IQueryMethods-Executea,b
>      at .$FSI_0003.main@() in C:\Development\CountriesParser\Script1.fsx:line 36

The line 36 is exact line of groupBy.

As I read in these pages, it should work
http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Linq.ComposableQuery/QueryExamples.html
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374.aspx

Comment: I do not see anything immediately wrong here - can you include which libraries are you referencing and what namespaces are open? And how is the `db` value created?

Comment: I edited my question and I added code before query, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a number of different SQL type providers for F# and I think your code uses community-driven one that does not support the `groupBy` construct at the moment.

1. The type `SqlDataProvider` comes from `SQLProvider` package and is documented [here](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/).
2. The `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders` library (also distributed with Visual Studio) is documented [here](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/) and exposes `SqlDataConnection` type.
3. You also mentioned ComposableQuery library documented [here](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Linq.ComposableQuery/), which is an extension that you can use on top of (2), but you're not doing that in your code.

The library (1) is nicer in a number of ways, but does not support the full query language yet, so you'll probably need to switch to (2).

To do that, reference just `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders` (you do not need the other two packages) and then use the `SqlDataConnection` type, following the [MSDN Walkthrough on the topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361033.aspx)